# Difficulty converting mysql_result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was following up a rather older tutorial on youtube and in the video he used `mysql_result` in this way:

```
return (mysql_result($result,0) == 1) ? true : false;
```

And I figured `mysql_result` is deprecated and wanted to do the exact same thing using `num_rows` and did it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
return(mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) ? true : false;
```

But it doesn't seem to be working and I can not figure out where I went wrong.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That COUNT will always return 1 row, you need to compare the value of the result, which can be 0,1,or more

Comment: I thought that was what i was doing when i used "return(mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) ? true : false;" .........

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows()` doesn't check any data values, just the number of rows, hence the function name `mysqli_num_rows()`.... you need to fetch the result, and check the actual value returned by the query

Comment: so what should i use instead???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) as user_count FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return(($row["user_count"]) === 1) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Thank you brother it actually worked.... You are a live saver and just one improvement, i think we should use '==' instead of '===' in the return statement.....Thank you again!!!!!!!!

Comment: Will do @Mark Baker